# Why is there a CS0433 error for Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert in my project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, json.net

In my ASP.NET MVC project, the following error occurs:

> Error CS0433 The type "JsonConvert" exists both in "Newtonsoft.Json, Version = 12.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 30ad4fe6b2a6aeed", and in "Newtonsoft.Json, Version = 6.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"

I checked the entire project and did not find in it a link or any mention of `Newtonsoft.Json, Version = 6.0.0.0`. I tried to remove `Newtonsoft.Json, Version = 6.0.0.0` and `12.0.0.0`, then installed the latest version, but the error does not go away. Please tell me what this may be connected with. I am completely at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have linked another NuGet package which requires Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.0.0.
You might have a look at your dependencies for each NuGet package or try recreating the whole solution.

Comment: How can I check package dependencies with Visual Studio 2019?